# How to add authorization to Microsoft Teams Bot in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, authorization, botframework, microsoft-teams

I hosted a Bot in Azure that works as intended, but I wanted to add authorization via Azure Active Directory.
I already set oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow and oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to true and checked ID-Token under authorization.

But when I go to my hosted Bots Url I still get this message:

AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.

Are there better ways for authorization or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see you've tagged this with Microsoft-Teams, so I'm assuming you're wanting to use this bot in Teams? If so, can you explain the scenario a little better? Are you just wanting *certain* user to be able to access the bot? Are you perhaps just trying to make sure users are *authenticated*?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough, its my first time asking a question here.
Its a bot that is connected with SharePoint and Microsoft Grap Api and is being used in MS Teams. The bot has Post endpoints for Flow to interact with. The "problem" is that it shouldn't be possible to just go to the Url of the Post endpoint and send something to the Bot. The Post endpoint has a Secret but it would be better if you had to log into your Azure Account first to authenticate before being able to send anything. But then i get the issue i wrote above.

Comment: No worries, just wanting to make sure I understand properly so I can help with the scenario. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear what you mean about "connected to SharePoint.." - do you mean the Bot calls into those products, using, say, app credentials, and that's why you want to authenticate the user? If so, you should have a look at [Authentication flow for Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot) as part of the Teams documentation.

Essentially, it involves sending a special kind of "card" response (if you've not send a Card, it means that, instead of sending a text message to the user, you're sending a kind of "mini form" inside the chat window). There's more  on cards [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference), but specifically later on in the doc is a part about the card you need, the [signin card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#signin-card).

The first article links to a second one with more detailed step-by-step instructions on getting it up and running, and getting the access token, as well as a link to a sample project. See [Add authentication to your Teams bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication).

Hope that helps.